# Creating a PIN code with secure text entry using a formatted text field with swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How would one go about creating a secure text entry text field which stores the text field (password) as a secure text field but places it in a label like the one below?

[image: Confirm Pin screenshot]

My approach is to use https://github.com/tkach/PinCodeTextField
However, when I import the Cocoapods my view controller cannot reference the delegate "PinCodeTextFieldDelegate". The error: "Use of undeclared type 'PinCodeTextFieldDelegate'" is displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be to create a hidden text field that becomes the first responder when the view appears, listen for text input and validate with its delegate methods, and update the view accordingly.

For the circles, use images, and toggle between empty and filled (or some other visual representation) as the number of digits in the hidden text field are entered/deleted.

There are probably quite a few other approaches, but this is the way I'd go.